# Em dash with other punctuation

Tags: punctuation

Proofreading my book:

I've consulted the *Chicago Manual of Style* and do not find this question answered directly.

Using em dashes to set off parenthetical material:

Within a clause an em dash is placed at each end.

At the end of a sentence, it is closed with a period.

What happens when the parenthetical material is placed at the end of the first of two independent clauses?

Example (dialogue): "It wasn’t much--mailroom and whatever little errands they needed done--but somehow Father convinced Hubert he needed to get a start somewhere."

Placing a comma after the second em dash seems fussy.  Following practice at the end of a sentence, the second em dash would be omitted and a comma used, but the situations do not feel exactly alike, and I think readers would be looking for the second em dash.  Using two em dashes and omitting the comma as unnecessary seems the most sensible to me.

What is best practice?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, a comma after the second em dash is not fussy, it is useless: An em dash is a bigger break than a comma, so you're done. With parentheses, you would still use the comma.

Comment: This question might be a better fit on English Language and Usage SE.